# O que são e como identificar agregados em DDD?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ddd

Em DDD existe a noção de agregado. Uma definição que já vi por aí é a seguinte

> Compostos de Entidades ou Objetos de Valores que são encapsulados numa única classe. O Agregado serve para manter a integridade do modelo. Elegemos uma classe para servir de raiz do Agregado. Quando algum cliente quiser manipular dados de uma das classes que compõem o Agregado, essa manipulação só poderá ser feita através da raiz.

Então basicamente a ideia de agregados em DDD é equivalente a ideia de composição em orientação a objetos? A relação de composição entre dois objetos é basicamente quando um atua como parte e o outro atua como todo. Desse jeito, quando fazemos uma composição está fazendo um agregado, sendo que o "todo" é o agregado? E nesse caso o que é a raiz?

O que realmente são agregados? Além disso, como identificamos agregados ao fazer o modelo de domínio?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Então basicamente a ideia de agregação em DDD é equivalente a ideia de composição em orientação a objetos?

**Não**. É muito comum tentar entender os design patterns do DDD confundindo-os com design patterns de orientação a objetos; e isto geralmente leva a enganos.

Apesar de que na prática o que mais vemos é DDD sendo implementando usando orientação a objetos <sub>(mentira, na prática quase não vemos DDD)</sub>, a rigor a orientação a objetos sequer é um requisito - DDD pode ser implementado utilizando-se outros paradigmas.

> O que realmente são agregações?

Em DDD, agregação é a estruturação de entidades e objetos de valor de forma coesa a fim de garantir a expressividade do domínio e a integridade destes objetos, uma vez que o acesso a eles só pode ser feito a partir da *entide raiz*.

> Como identificamos agregações ao fazer o modelo de domínio?

Vamos dar uma olhada na estrutura básica de uma agregação:

```
-> Entidade Raiz
    -> Entidade agregada
        -> Objetos de valor
    -> Entidade agregada
        -> Objetos de valor
    -> Objetos de valor
```

- **Objetos de valor:** eles não possuem nenhuma identidade, de modo que eles sempre serão parte de uma entidade. Eles farão parte de uma agregação no momento que a sua entidade for a raiz desta agregação ou sua entidade fizer parte desta agregação.
- **Entidades**: elas possuem identidade global no domínio (ou global no contexto no caso de um domínio com mais de um modelo - ver *bounded context*). Ou seja, você é capaz de diferenciar um objeto do outro pela sua identidade e não apenas por suas características.
- **Entidades que fazem parte de uma agregação**: elas possuem identidade, mas não global. Para fazer sentido no domínio, a identidade delas precisa ser precedida da identidade de uma outra entidade (uma "entidade pai", por assim dizer).
- **Entidades raiz**: uma entidade com identidade global será a raiz de uma agregação se ela depender de outras entidades (que não possuam identidade global) para ajudar a descrevê-la. Essas outras entidades então serão agregadas a esta entidade raiz - e daí temos uma agregação.

O domínio determina quais objetos possuem identidade e quais possuem identidade global. Os que possuem identidade global podem constituir a raiz de uma agregação e aqueles cuja identidade é dependente desta entidade raiz, serão agregados a ela. Os objetos de valor, por sua vez, estão sempre juntos da sua entidade.

## Exemplo de agregação

Um exemplo em um certo domínio ou modelo poderia ser:

```
-> Livro (entidade raiz)
    -> Reviews de clientes (entidades agregadas)
    -> Reviews editoriais (entidades agregadas)
    -> Formatos disponíveis - papel, kindle, pdf (objetos de valor)
```

Neste caso, o livro tem uma identidade global no domínio ou no modelo. Sua identidade é o seu nome mais o nome do seu autor.

Os reviews também têm identidade, que é o nome do cliente ou da entidade editorial, e eventualmente a data de publicação. Mas veja que a identidade de um review só faz sentido se precedida pela identidade do próprio livro - embora seja importante identificar cada review de um livro (quem escreveu o review e quando), ele não serve para mais do que um livro e não existirá sem um livro.

Já os formatos disponíveis não possuem nenhuma identidade - um livro simplesmente está disponível em alguns dos formatos existentes.

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que pude entender do conceito, o `agregado` é muito similar à composição em POO.

Vamos supor um carro, que tem motor, portas e rodas.

Nisso, temos o **agregado** carro, com as outras três, motor, portas e rodas sendo classes agregadas à classe carro.

Um objeto `carro` tem portas, motor e rodas, e essas partes **não têm vida própria fora do objeto**, isto é, estão subordinadas ao objeto `carro`.

Se um cliente quiser manipular uma porta ou um motor, ele terá de fazer isso usando o objeto `carro`, mas **não poderá** ao usar a porta ou motor selecionado.

Respondendo às outras perguntas...

Um agregado seria um conjunto de classes provindas de uma relação de agregação. Como a composição é uma agregação mais restrita (na agregação, as partes têm vida fora do todo, na composição, **náo**)

Você pode identificar um agregado no modelo do domínio levando em conta o banco de dados, por exemplo, se você vai armazenar tipos diferentes de portas, rodas e motores no sistema, e os carros podem fazer uso de diferentes combinações dessas partes, você pode fazer uso desse agregado que citei, um carro com portas, motores e pneus.

Comment: "Você pode identificar um agregado no modelo do domínio levando em conta o banco de dados". Não cara, você não pode fazer isso, se o fizer você está corrompendo o Domain-Driven Design. Eric Evans foi bastante enfático com relação a isso e o Scott Millet colocou em seu Livro sobre Padrões e práticas do DDD que focar o seu Modelo de Domínio no seu Modelo de Dados é temerário e ainda suja o seu desenvolvimento, ele tem de ser do Domínio pro Banco de Dados e não o contrário, senão você estará desenvolvendo uma Big Ball of Mud (Grande Bola de Lama) por causa da complexidade extra dada ao "dominio"