# Dúvida referente a utilização de Aggregates em DDD

Tags: ddd

Estou ferindo os princípios do DDD e conceito de Aggregates se utilizar um agrregate dentro de outro conforme o cenário abaixo?

**Contexto de um pequeno e-commerce.**

**Aggregate - Store**

```
public class Store
{
  public Guid Id { get; private set; }
  public string ShopName { get; private set; }
  public int Phone { get; private set; }
  public string ShopUrl { get; private set; }
  public IList<Vendor> Vendors { get; private set; }
  
  ///Aqui é um aggregate, pois uma loja tem uma coleção de produtos
  public IList<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}
```

**Aggregate - Product**

```
public class Product
{
    ///To do
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se está referenciado somente pelo ID, tudo bem, é aceitável. Se estiver tratando o identificador dele, mais alguns atributos como um [VO](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html), tudo bem, é aceitável.
Porém, utilizar um dentro do outro, usar com o ciclo de vida e casos de uso, é errado.

- [O que realmente é DDD e quando ele se aplica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49591/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-como-identificar-agregados-em-ddd)
- [O que são e como identificar agregados em DDD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19548/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-ddd-e-quando-ele-se-aplica/40962#40962)

Comment: Obrigado! Dei uma pesquisa e entendi o conceito.